# Use of undeclared type 'AttributedString'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8-beta4

Xcode 8 beta 4 no longer recognizes Foundation class `AttributedString`.

I've reproduced it in this simple playground example:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

let attrStr1 = NSAttributedString()
let attrStr2 = AttributedString()  // Use of undeclared type 'AttributedString'
```

Since `AttributedString` was available in older Xcode 8 Swift 3 betas, I imagine this is a `Foundation` bug that needs to be fixed, rather than some source code error in Playground?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug.  I think they reversed the naming  change from NSAttributeString->AttributedString back to use the prefix.  Presumably to keep the NS prefix consistent in Foundation.   Overall there are lots more naming changes in beta 4 than I expected.  Most are obvious, some are trickier.

Comment: @MattWeinecke and @PetahChristian: interesting reversal from Apple if true. I can't find any mention of from it from the Xcode 8 Beta 4 release notes though. I'd personally welcome back the `NS` prefix. As there are too many things to remember now: `Data` is a struct but `NSData` is a class; same with `URL`, etc.

Comment: I had thought it was weird for example that AttributedString had dropped the prefix but not NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: I have tested here and you need to use NSAttributedString. My project doesn't even compile with AttributedString.

Comment: Found the reason explained in [SE-0086](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/commit/bea5eab614b954775754639fb83a957a180152e1) @LeoDabus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although undocumented in the Xcode release notes, a version 2 update to Swift evolution proposal [SE-0086 Drop NS Prefix in Swift Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md) has added the "NS" prefix back to several Foundation classes which previously dropped the prefix.

The reason is as follows:

> If the class is planned to have a value-type equivalent in the near future, then keep the NS prefix. Examples: NSAttributedString, NSRegularExpression, NSPredicate.

So, the Swift `AttributedString` type will return at *some* point, as a struct next time, instead of being a class.

It sounds like some of these improvements will be "a focus area for Swift 4." For now, it's necessary to revert back to using the `NSAttributedString` class.

*If you're curious to know how many types were affected by the SE-0086 v2 update, it looks like the [revision](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/commit/bea5eab614b954775754639fb83a957a180152e1) affects ~32 types which had previously dropped the NS prefix for Swift 3.*