# What is syntax for placeholder usage in regular expression in Predicate?

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate, predicate

I want to specify my value in regular expression, how can I do it?

What I am doing:

```
request.predicate = Predicate(format: "entityProperty MATCHES [c] '[^0123]%@'", myValue)
```

Observing the result, I can say that %@ is parsed as a characters in the regex string, no value is placed instead of it

Here is some [explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) on usage of regular expressions with predicates, but no information about placeholders for values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Solution** would work for:

1. `myValue` is representing valid regex pattern.
2. `myValue` may not contain single quotes (`'`).

If `myValue` may contain single quote, this would work:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "entityProperty MATCHES [c] %@", "[^1234]" + myValue)
```

And if `myValue` is not a regex pattern and may contain some meta-characters, you may need to write something like this:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "entityProperty MATCHES [c] %@", "[^1234]"+NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: myValue))
```

Anyway, you need to remember:

> Single or double quoting variables (or substitution variable strings)
>   cause %@, %K, or $variable to be interpreted as a literal in the
>   format string and so prevent any substitution.

[Parser Basics (Predicate Programming Guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW2)

(I used `NSPredicate` as `Predicate` is not available in Xcode 8 beta 6.)

Comment: @OOPer, thank you. Do you know how I can combine statements like CONTAINS text0 AND CONTAINS text1 in predicate?

Comment: @spin_eight, `NSPredicate(format: "entityProperty CONTAINS %@ AND entityProperty CONTAINS %@", text0, text1)` would work. If I may be missing something, please give me a little more context.

Comment: @OOPer My mistake, apologize me, i have read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38723245/6433023) and get more idea about it.

Comment: @NDoc, I know I could mistake, so I should welcome all sorts of comments. Please do not hesitate to pointing my mistakes in the future. One thing I recommend to you that you'd better respect other sources than SO. Good luck for you and for your apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.predicate = Predicate(format: "entityProperty MATCHES [c] '[^0123]\(myValue)'")
```

**Solution:**
instead of `%@` placeholder use string substitution:
"prefixSomeText\(myValue)suffixSomeText"